# didSelectItemAtIndexPath of UICollectionView is not called

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

After a couple of days of going crazy I wasn't able to find a solution to my issue. The problem is this: After selecting a cell in a `UICollectionView` the method `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` is not called.

My views structure is:

[image: Views structure]

This view is managed by a controller which has following methods:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    initCategoriesCollection()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func initCategoriesCollection(){
    let ccVC : CategoriesCollectionViewController  =  UIStoryboard(name:"CandidateProfile",bundle:nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("categoriesController") as! CategoriesCollectionViewController;
    addChildViewController(ccVC)
    ccVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.containerView.frame.size.width, self.containerView.frame.size.height);
    containerView.addSubview(ccVC.view)

    ccVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

}
```

The container view above has the following structure:

[image]

And this container view is managed by a ViewController which implements these methods:

```
// tell the collection view how many cells to make
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.e1Categories.count
}

// make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell

    // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
    cell.categoryName.text = self.e1Categories[indexPath.item].string
    cell.categoryName.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.categoryName.sizeToFit()
    cell.categoryName.textAlignment = .Center
    cell.categoryCircle.makeCircle()

    return cell
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
}
```

Does anyone know what is happening? I have tried to remove ScrollView because maybe It is intercepting touch events, but it is still not working at all.
After reading some other Questions here, in Stackoverflow, none of them has a solution for me.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I have connected my `delegate` and `dataSource` through the Storyboard, as you can see in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: has the `delegate` connected?

Comment: Adding `ccVC.delegate = self` should do the trick in your `initCategoriesCollection` method

Comment: @holex Yes, I have connected it through the Storyboard. I have edited the post with a capture of that.
@EBDOKUM When i try it next issue raises: `Value of type 'CategoriesCollectionViewController' has no member 'delegate'´

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all thanks for give me the hints to solve my problem. Following them and trying to assign the parent controller as `delegate` of `ccvc.collectionView`, It said that there wasn't any `delegate` in the child ViewController. 
My problem was that I thought that if assigned both `delegate` and `dataSource` via `Storyboard` It would work out, but It wouldn't.

So I decided to implement both Delegate and Datasource protocols in parent controller, remove child controller and It works like a charm now.
Maybe I was misunderstanding concepts when I used the `Storyboard`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In your `initCategoriesCollection()`, you are creating a new `CategoriesCollectionViewController`:

```
let ccVC : CategoriesCollectionViewController  =  UIStoryboard(name:"CandidateProfile",bundle:nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("categoriesController") as! CategoriesCollectionViewController;
```

According to you:

> And this container view is managed by a ViewController which implements these methods:

Then you are adding the `ccVC` to another `controller` that implement the `delegate` func `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. Therefore the `delegate` set on storyboard is not to the correct `controller` that are managing it.

You should be updating the `delegate` since you are adding it to another `controller` that is implementing it. Try update to this

```
let ccVC : CategoriesCollectionViewController  =  UIStoryboard(name:"CandidateProfile",bundle:nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("categoriesController") as! CategoriesCollectionViewController;
addChildViewController(ccVC)
ccvc.collectionView.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

```
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self
```

set delegate and datasource UIViewController class and not in storyboard